# Can't go through "Requested entity was not found" error with Speech-to-Text API

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I call Cloud Speech-to-Text API in a Cloud Function triggered by a GCS event.
Doing it outside of a Cloud Function (running `node index.js`) is perfectly fine, but my error comes afterwards.

Using [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/Code), I believed that the error was due to an authentification issue, but I tried several things and I am not so sure now.

My code is :

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const nl = require('@google-cloud/language');
const client_nl = new nl.LanguageServiceClient();
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const client_speech = new speech.SpeechClient();

exports.getRecording = (data,context) => {
  const file = data;
  if (file.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
    // Ignore file deletions
    return true;
  } else if (!new RegExp(/\.(wav|mp3)/g).test(file.name)) {
    // Ignore changes to non-audio files
    return true;
  }

  console.log(`Analyzing gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`);

  const bucket = storage.bucket(file.bucket);
  const audio = {
    uri: 'gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}'
  };

  // Configure audio settings for BoF recordings
  const audioConfig = {
    encoding: 'LINEAR16',
    sampleRateHertz: 44100,
    languageCode: 'fr-FR'
  };

  const request = {
    audio: audio,
    config: audioConfig,
  };

  return client_speech.recognize(request)
    .then(([transcription]) => {
      const filename = `analysis.json`;
      console.log(`Saving gs://${file.bucket}/${filename}`);

      return bucket
        .file(filename)
        .save(JSON.stringify(transcription, null, 2));
  });
```

I then deploy with :
`gcloud functions deploy getRecording --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-resource trigger-bucket-id --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize --service-account my-service-account`

What I tried :

1. `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/file/keyfile.json`
2. added a `config.json` file with `"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS":"./keyfile.json"` inside, and the keyfile in the root project and a `require('./config.json')` in the `index.js`
3. added an options json

```
const options = {
    projectId: 'my-project-id',
    keyFilename: './key-file.json'
  };
const client_speech = new speech.SpeechClient(options);
```

I keep getting this error and would need some help

```sh
D      getRecording  573287126069013  2019-06-07 15:03:09.609  Function execution started
       getRecording  573287126069013  2019-06-07 15:03:09.789  Analyzing gs://my-bucket/audio_trimed.wav
D      getRecording  573287126069013  2019-06-07 15:03:10.979  Function execution took 1372 ms, finished with status: 'error'
E      getRecording  573291408785013  2019-06-07 15:03:11.990  Error: Requested entity was not found.
                                                                   at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:101:45)
                                                                   at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:194:15)
                                                                   at Http2CallStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:459:23)
                                                                   at Http2CallStream.endCall (/srv/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:63:18)
                                                                   at handlingTrailers (/srv/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:152:18)
                                                                   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bruce was right, I finally spotted the mistake.
I just couldn't see that it was written
`uri:'gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}'`

and not

```
uri: `gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`
```

(yes the mistake was tiny but could have been avoided with more testing...

Answer (score 1):

Does any of [this code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/blob/master/samples/quickstart.js) help?
There are a few StackOverflow posts that might help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959479/google-speech-api-how-to-pickup-results-of-my-asyncrecognize-request), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086098/error-5-not-found-requested-entity-was-not-found-on-longrunningrecognize)

I suggest more verbose logging / debugging.
For example, can you prove out that these two lines do what you expect?  Does the string produce a well formed uri?

```
const bucket = storage.bucket(file.bucket);
  const audio = {
    uri: 'gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}'
  };
```

Let us know if you find a solution

Comment: Hey @Bruce thank you for your answer. 

My problem here is that I don't meet any issue while running **locally** the quickstart that you provided me. My problem comes when I use this very same code in a Cloud Function.



In my code, you can see the line
`console.log('Analyzing gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}');`
This prints the expected values, and the next line is not changing the file variable